# Error: document.styleSheets[0] is undefined как "пропадающий дефект". Моя ошибка или баг браузера? Как защититься?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Самописный сайт без фреймворков. Есть простейший скрипт для работы со стилями, который добавляет/удаляет/меняет стили элементов (в нём ошибок нет, он просто сокращается длинные обращения к свойствам элемента или добавление классов в таблицу стилей до коротких команд). После первой загрузки, и в 99% случаев всё работает корректно. Но если активно кликать во всё на сайте, и пока происходит анимация/перерисовка кликнуть в "обновить страницу", а так же иногда в случае длительного простоя(?!), происходит странное.

Ломаются все скрипты добавления/удаления стилей из элементов (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cssRules' of undefined`), потому что таблица стилей `document.styleSheets[0]` вдруг становится `undefined`. Вывожу в консоль

```
console.log('Проверка существования таблицы стилей');
console.log(document);
console.log(document.styleSheets);
console.log(document.styleSheets.length);
console.log(document.styleSheets[0]);
```

На выходе: массив `document.styleSheets` имеет длину `length: 0` и `length: 1` одновременно!!!

```
StyleSheetList {length: 0}
0: CSSStyleSheet {cssRules: CSSRuleList, …}
length: 1
__proto__: StyleSheetList
```

[image: (см. картинку)]

Как это вообще?!

Когда всё работает, `length: 1` всюду, как и ожидается.

Данный баг ловится только в Chrome (89.0.4389.90). В Firefox, как бы я бешено, неистово не накликивал и не обновлял, проблемы нет.

Отправлять баг в Chrome? Ждать пока его починят? Можно ли написать годную защиту от этой ерундовой ситуации, так чтобы она не подвешивала сайт? setTimeOut не решает проблему. Если при обновлении length определилась с ошибкой, через секунду-две-пять ничего не меняется.

Плагины выключал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала теория:

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что браузер при обновлении страницы берёт скрипты из кеша, а вот стайлшит к моменту исполнения скрипта ещё не готов.

В консоль девтулза отдаётся ссылка на стайлшит, поэтому при развороте информации о нём через несколько секунд после работы скрипта, консоль отдаёт длину массива == 1, потому что стайлшит к тому времени уже готов. Отсюда такое противоречие.

Теперь решения.

Решение 1. для единственной функции, обращающейся к стилям.
Нужно проверить внутри функции наличие стайлшита и если его нет вызвать её рекурсивно с теми же аргументами по таймауту.

Решение 2. Для фреймворка, когда функций много на асинк-эвейтах.

```
    const cooldown = 30;
    let correct = false;
    let skip = false; // флаг пропуска проверок

    export const pause = async (ms = cooldown) =>
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    const simpleGetCSS = styleSheetNum => document.styleSheets[styleSheetNum];

    const checkCSS = styleSheet => {
      // проверяет указанный стайлшит, но делает это не чаще, чем раз в cooldown
      if (!skip && styleSheet && styleSheet.cssRules) {
        correct = true;
      } else {
        correct = false;
        skip ?
          setTimeout(() => {skip = false}, cooldown):
          skip = true;
      }
    };

    export const getStyleSheet = async (styleSheetNum = 0, ms = 0) => {
      let styleSheet = simpleGetCSS(styleSheetNum);
      checkCSS(styleSheet);
      if (correct) {
        return styleSheet;
      } else {
        console.log('Ошибка поиска таблицы стилей #' + styleSheetNum);
        ms == 0 ? ms = cooldown/1.25 : await pause(ms);
        return await getStyleSheet(styleSheetNum, ms*1.25);
      }
    };

    // Использование
    // Функция добавляет правило в таблицу стилей
    const addRuleToCSS = async (
      ruletxt = '.class-name {ruleName: rule; }', styleSheetNum = 0) => {
      const styleSheet = await getStyleSheet(styleSheetNum);
    styleSheet.insertRule(ruletxt, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
    };
```

Код пробует быстро добыть стайлшит, проверяет его, и только в случае ошибки начинает ожидать окончание паузы и заново вызывать и проверять стайлшит, с каждым рекурсивным вызовом наращивает паузу на 25%.

Если какая-то другая функция во время кулдауна попробует достать стайлшит, так же будет совершена одна попытка, но следующая проверка затормозится переменной skip, то есть это своего рода троттлинг, общий для всех.