# Повторный запуск функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу вашей помощи, уже 3 день ломаю голову...
Суть проблемы в чем. Пишу бота для автоматической покупки игровых вещей (через АПИ плошадки) который должен проходить по массиву выгодных вещей и сравнивать цены, если цена изменилась, то повышает цену на 1 копейку, все бы ничего, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу запустить повторно функцию проверки цен, то есть нужно после завершения цикла проверки, подождать 5-10 секунд и запустить повторно эту функцию, но из за того что для изменения цен используются Promise, я не могу найти "триггер, точку..." после которого я бы мог запустить повторно функцию.
Прошу помогите.

**Функция проверки цен**

```
function placingOrders( ) {
try {
    console.log( ' placingOrders ' );

    Object.keys(profitItemsList).map( (itemList, index) => {
        let classid = profitItemsList[itemList].id.split( '-' )[0];
        let instanceid = profitItemsList[itemList].id.split( '-' )[1];
        let name = profitItemsList[itemList].name;
        if( marketBestOffer[name] ) { 
            if( marketBestOffer[name].best_offer < profitItemsList[itemList].maxBuyPrice ) {
                if( oldOrderPrice[itemList] == 0 || oldOrderPrice[itemList] == undefined || oldOrderPrice[itemList] != marketBestOffer[name].best_offer ) {
                    ProcessOrder( itemList, name, classid, instanceid, ++marketBestOffer[name].best_offer );
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if( placingOrdersTimer ) {
        console.log( ' ======================================== ' );
        clearTimeout( placingOrdersTimer );
        placingOrdersTimer = setTimeout( placingOrders, 5000 );
    } else placingOrdersTimer = setTimeout( placingOrders, 5000 );
} catch(e) {
    console.log( '[placingOrders]: (' +e+ ')' );
}
```

}

**Функция изменения цены**

```
function ProcessOrder( index, name, classid, instanceid, price ) {
try {
    limiter.schedule( () => {
        getHTTP( marketURL + '/api/ProcessOrder/'+classid+'/'+instanceid+'/'+price+'/?key=' + marketApiKey )
        .then( (data) => {
            try {
                let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
                if( json_data['success'] ) {
                    let class_ins_name = classid+ '-' +instanceid+ '-' +name;
                    if( price != 0 ) {
                        oldOrderPrice[index] = json_data['price'];
                        console.log( '[Buy: '+json_data['way']+']['+class_ins_name+'] Ордер обновлен. Новая цена: ' +Math.round( json_data['price'] )/100+ 'р.' );
                    } else console.log( '[Buy: '+json_data['way']+']['+class_ins_name+'] Ордер удален!' );
                }
            } catch(e) {
                console.log( '[ProcessOrder:buy]: ('+e+')' );
            } 
        });
    });
    
} catch(e) {
    console.log( '[ProcessOrder]: ('+e+')' );
}
```

}

**Функция getHTTP**

```
function getHTTP( url ) {
return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpReq();
    xhr.open( 'GET', url, true );
    //xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode' );
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if( xhr.status == 200 ) {
            resolve( this.responseText );
            /* setTimeout( () => { 
                resolve( this.responseText );
            }, 200 ); */
        } else {
            var error = new Error( this.statusText );
            error.code = this.status;
            reject( error );
        }
    }
    xhr.send( null );
} );
```

}

Comment: я тоже с промиссами и асинхронщиной дня 3 разбирался, это норма))

Comment: `я не могу найти "триггер, точку..." после которого я бы мог запустить повторно функцию` - вы не знаете где (в какой момент)  код заканчивает свою работу?

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите вообще всё на промиссы, а лучше через async/await.

Вместо таймаутов внутри функции удобнее использовать таймаут-промисс

```
export const pause = async (ms = 1000) =>
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Иcпользование функции внутри 'placingOrders'

```
async function placingOrders( ) {
  try {
    ...
    if( placingOrdersTimer ) {
       await pause(5000)
       await placingOrdersTimer = await placingOrders());
    }else{...}
  }
}
```

В конечном итоге цепочка вызовов:

```
const go = async () => {
  const priceList = await getHTTP(url);
  let orders = await placingOrders(); // 
  await ProcessOrder();
}
go();
```

Comment: Посмотрите пример асинхронного рекурсивного вызова с таймаутом (как раз то, что вы хотите сделать) и без заодно повторов во время таймаута https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257072/error-document-stylesheets0-is-undefined-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0/1341847#1341847

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо DraKoan за подсказку о async/await, в целом помогло, но одна проблема все еще осталась, скрипт в рандомный промежуток времени останавливает...

Не много опишу работу скрипта, возможно кто то поможет, ибо я уже все мозги сломал...
В общем и целом, есть общий массив, который генерируется из выгодных вещей для покупки, далее этот массив разбивается на части по 100 записей (так как апи площадки за один запрос может принимать не болеет 100 вещей), далее, из этих "маленьких" массивов получаем цену каждого предмета и записываем цену в другой массив вида `marketBestOffer[name].best_offer`, перед записью есть промежуточный массив, в который записывается ответ от апи после каждого запроса "маленьких" массивов, а дальше уже я сравниваю промежуточный массив с общим и если они равняются, то вызываю уже функцию `placingOrders()` где собственно уже и происходит изменение цен. А проблема появляется на моменте сравнения промежуточного и общего массивом, общий понятно не меняется, а вот промежуточный бывает не равняется общему, хотя должен, с чем это связано я понять не могу, по этому прошу мозговитых людей этого форума о помощи.

Код где генерируются "чанки" - Они же "маленькие" массивы

```
async function arrayChunk( itemList ) {
    // console.log( '[arrayChunk]' );
    itemList = itemList || [];
    let chunk = 100;
    for( let i = 0, il = itemList.length; i < il; i += chunk ) {
        await itemMakeList( itemList.slice( i, i + chunk ) );
    }
    // console.log( '=======================================' );
}

async function itemMakeList( itemList ) {
    /*
        {
            id: '4580329655-0-Banger Thompson',
            maxBuyPrice: 4401,
            maxsellprice: 9999999,
            percent: 58.43,
            buy: true,
            sell: false
        }
    */

    Object.keys(itemList).map( list => {
        MassInfoList.push( itemList[list].id.split( '-' )[0]+ '_' +itemList[list].id.split( '-' )[1] );
    });
    
    if( MassInfoList == '' ) return;
    await marketMassInfo( MassInfoList );
    MassInfoList = [];
    await pause(300);
}
```

Часть где записывается цена, промежуточный массив и проверка провежуточного и общего массивов

```
async function marketMassInfo( list ) {
    try {
        /* const massInfo = await postHTTP( marketURL+ '/api/MassInfo/0/2/0/1?key=' +marketApiKey, list );
        (async() => {
            let json_massInfo = await JSON.parse(massInfo);
            if( json_massInfo != null ) {
                for( let i = 0, il = json_massInfo.results.length; i < il; i++ ) {
                    arr.push( json_massInfo.results[i] );
                }
                if( arr.length == profitItemsList.length ) {
                    console.log( arr.length, profitItemsList.length );
                    for( let i = 0, il = arr.length; i < il; i++ ) {
                        let name = arr[i].info.market_hash_name;
                        let best_offer = arr[i].buy_offers.best_offer;
                        marketBestOffer[name] = {};
                        marketBestOffer[name].best_offer = best_offer;
                    }
                    arr = [];
                    if( marketBestOffer ) {
                        placingOrders();
                    }
                }
                
            }
        })(); */

            postHTTP( marketURL+ '/api/MassInfo/0/2/0/1?key=' +marketApiKey, list )
            .then( (data) => {
                (async() => {
                    let json_massInfo = await JSON.parse(data);
                    // console.log(json_massInfo);
                    if( json_massInfo.success && json_massInfo != null ) {
                        await( () => {
                            // console.log( 'MassInfo 2' );
                            for( let i = 0, il = json_massInfo.results.length; i < il; i++ ) {
                                arr.push( json_massInfo.results[i] );
                            }
                            // console.log( 'MassInfo 3' );
                            console.log( '1 '+arr.length, profitItemsList.length );
                        } )();
                        // console.log( 'MassInfo 4' );
                        await( async() => {
                            // console.log( 'MassInfo 5' );
                            await( () => {
                                // console.log( 'MassInfo 6' );
                                for( let i = 0, il = arr.length; i < il; i++ ) {
                                    let name = arr[i].info.market_hash_name;
                                    let best_offer = arr[i].buy_offers.best_offer;
                                    marketBestOffer[name] = {};
                                    marketBestOffer[name].best_offer = best_offer;
                                }
                                // console.log( 'MassInfo 6 ' +arr.length+ ' - ' +profitItemsList.length );
                            })();
                            // console.log( 'MassInfo 7' );
                            await( async() => {
                                // console.log( 'MassInfo 8' );
                                console.log( 'MassInfo 2 '+placing+ ' - ' +arr.length+ ' - ' +profitItemsList.length );
                                if( arr.length == profitItemsList.length ) {
                                    // console.log( 'MassInfo 9' );
                                    if( marketBestOffer && !placing ) {
                                        
                                        console.log( 'MassInfo 3 '+placing+ ' - ' +arr.length+ ' - ' +profitItemsList.length );
                                        // console.log( 'placingOrders' );
                                        arr = [];
                                        await placingOrders();
                                        // console.log( 'MassInfo 11' );
                                    }
                                    // arr = [];
                                    // console.log( 'MassInfo 12' );
                                    /* await( () => {
                                        // console.log( 'MassInfo 13' );
                                        arr = [];
                                        console.log( 'MassInfo 3 '+placing+ ' - ' +arr.length+ ' - ' +profitItemsList.length );
                                    } )(); */
                                    
                                    // console.log( 'MassInfo 14' );
                                }
                                // console.log( 'MassInfo 15' );
                            })();
                            // console.log( 'MassInfo 16' );
                            
                        } )();
                        // console.log( 'MassInfo 17' );
                    }
                    // console.log( 'MassInfo 18' );
                })();
                
            });

    } catch(e) {
        console.log( '[marketMassInfo]: (' +e+ ')' );
    }
}
```

Если наглядно, то выглядит это так
[image: Скриншот]

195 - Это размер общего массива
100-200-295 - Это размер промежуточного массива и он отличатся, а не должен